# How to manipulate the screen width via js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, responsive-design, viewport

I'll try to explain my use case here. In my site I have a break point for desktop view, and break point for tablet view (which is more compact). I'm trying to add a function to allow seeing the tablet view when browsing from desktop, cause some members prefer the compact design in their desktop as well.

For doing that, I figured I would need to trick the '@media(max-width:X)' query. I'm looking for a JS code that can manipulate the screen width value, so when the browser calculates max-width, it would be against a value that I specified.

One thing to note, this is suppose to work on desktop browsers, so the meta viewport can't be used here.

Comment: Screen width is the width of the actual viewing hardware. You can't change that with JavaScript. Users can of course re-size their browser windows manually, or use a trick like the Firefox `CTRL-SHIFT-M` facility.

Comment: One solution can be : Add the class `tablet` or `desktop` to the `body` tag. Style your elements differently using sub-classes. Then you can manipulate these classes with JS. I haven't tried this yet, though.

Comment: What's the usecase for this? Is it used for testing or for production use (customers/visitors should use this)?

Comment: Members of the site should use it

Answer (score 3):

One solution is to apply a specific class (e.g: `.tablet`) to the body.

```
<body class="tablet"></body>
```

In your CSS:

```
@media screen and (/* your query */) {
   .tablet .my-class {
        /* tablet specific stuff */
    }
}
```

You could then remove the `.tablet` class and replace it with `.desktop` via JavaScript

```
var body = document.body;

var switchToDesktop = function() {
    body.className = body.className.replace('tablet', 'desktop');
}

var switchToTablet = function() {
    body.className = body.className.replace('desktop', 'tablet');
}

var toggleView = function() {
    (body.className.indexOf("tablet") > -1) ?
        switchToDesktop() :
        switchToTablet();
}
```

If you are using **SASS** or **LESS**, you can nest the tablet-specific styles.

```
@media screen and (/* your query */) {
   .tablet {
        h1 {
            /* tablet specific h1 */
        }
        .my-div {
            color: red;
        }
        /* etc... */
    }
}
```